# PHP curl_exec stops execution of the rest of the script without error logs

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a php script running with curl and reporting setup as such, but it stops executing on the line with the `curl_exec()` method, and there are no errors thrown:

```
$fields = array(
        'auth' => array(
               'cId' => 'DEADBEEF-8675309-8675309-123123-4321',
               'sig' => 'Not really a signature',
               'data' => array(
                    'field' => 'pat',
                    'value' => '12',
                    'id1' => 'lasagna',
                    'id2' => 'peperoni'
                )

        ),
        'item1' => 'QPFMgH1TnCTLrylGeNs8yzYVVXxUgR0RHwj9jNwgXJJEfxODdoOKDOJLv66CSU5XKRfu4KYtDJB5rAmngxNrRDFpWU69oHMTlZoHAewuy3ft',
        'item2' => 'gMiGdw==',
        'tokenList' => array(
                "token", "list"
        )
);

$postfields = json_encode($fields);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$curl = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/endpoint');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//$result = curl_exec($curl);

echo "before curl_exec" . "\n\n";
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
echo "after curl_exec" . "\n\n";

print_r($response);
```

EDIT:  forgot to include the line with json_encode for the $fields variable to pass to curl_setopt();

Comment: Try to separate the `json_encode` and the `curl_exec` and debug the two variables

Comment: you can use `try {} catch(Exception $e) {trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

}` and try this  `$response = curl_exec($curl); ` you  dont need  `json_encode ` while using `curl_exec`

Comment: Sorry I should have added the post body as well.  I think I need the json_encode in order to be able to convert the $fields into a json for the post body.  I will try what you guys mentioned and update you on what I get.   Thank you.

Comment: you didnt try `curl_error()`?

Comment: dilec, that won't help. If you knew the command or read the manual you would have seen 'Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.'. It doesn't throw an exception, so trying and catching is no use here.https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: @delboy1978uk I don't think that works because it just stops execution after curl_exec.   Not sure if the body of the post request is malformed, or I'm just missing something.

Comment: do both echoes come out?

Comment: set smaller `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`  and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and check if it helps

Comment: @delboy1978uk only the first one, "before curl_exec".

Comment: @Alex  That helped.  It now executes the rest of the code, but I get no return form curl_exec.

Comment: try curl_error() now then. `echo $response ? $response : curl_error();`

Comment: This is what I get from curl_error().  

```Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received```

It's weird because I can hit the endpoint just fine through Postman, I don't know why I'm having such a hard time with curl_exec().

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

---

you put the "post" data into `$fields` but then...

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```

...you're passing `$postFields` to curl.

---

Assuming this is a typo, fixing with

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

won't work.

If the parameter used for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an **array** it must be an associative array where **keys** and **values** are strings (or values that can be casted/converted to strings).

In your case `$fields` is an array where some values are arrays. That won't work (and raises a warning "array to string conversion").

---

You set an header that specifies that the data sent with the request is in JSON format

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

If you want to send the data into `$fields` as **JSON** with a `POST` request you can do it this way:

```
$fields = array( /* ... */ );

$json_fields = json_encode( $fields );

$curl = curl_init( 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_fields );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json',
                                          'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_fields) ] );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );

$response = curl_exec( $curl );

$response_data = json_decode( $response );
```

---

If still something needs to be fixed proceed with debugging by steps to isolate the problem:

```
// 1 - Check curl error

$errnum = curl_errno( $curl );
$errstr = curl_strerror( $errnum );

echo "Error: $errnum - $errstr\n";

// 2 - Check http status code of the response

$status = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

echo "Status: $status\n";

// 3 - Inspect the response before coverting to JSON

echo "Response:\n";
var_export( $response );
echo "\n";
```

Comment: I somehow missed copying the encode line over, my fault.  $postfields is my json encoded variable ($postfields = json_encode($fields);) .  Error on my part with the post on stackoverflow, but I already had that, sorry.  I'll probably try using python or something else to do these calls.   I shouldn't have such a hard time when postman works just fine.  Thank you though, I'll try your debugging portion before I move onto to something else to test with.

Comment: I have the same issue, regarding the 3 debugging steps, I get `Error: 0 - No error Status: 0`. Curl to `https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json` works, whereas to `localhost:4000/public/ser.php` the curl_exec hangs with result see above. In browser and from sh curl, it works.